# Store polymorphic hasMany: an ember bug?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

If I have the following models:

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Bar = App.Foo.extend({
  foos: DS.hasMany('foo',{
    polymorphic: true, async: true
  })
});
```

I get an error when I try to save "foos". Is there something else I should be doing?

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var store = this.get('store');
    f1 = store.createRecord(
      'foo', { name: 'foo'});
    b2 = store.createRecord(
      'bar', { name: 'bar' } );
    return b2;
  },
  afterModel: function( b2 ) {
    p = b2.get('foos').then(function(foos) {
      foos.addRecord(f1);
      return foos.save().then(function(){ 
        return b2.save().then(function(){ 
          console.log('ok');
          return b2;
        });
      });
    });
    return p;
  }
});
```

The error is: "Cannot set property 'store' of undefined" -- it seems that in the innards, an array of ids is passed (rather than ids and types) -- and then modelFor fails.

Thanks!

**Edit**: jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EnOqUxe/20/edit

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is a bug... related to a similar problem with belongsTo. [See discussion](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1535).

Here is my fix in coffeescript. NB I get the private data about the related object(s) from the cache, rather than wait for the promise: I think its not a good idea to force the server to send related objects in order to serialize a given object. However, there should probably be "official" interfaces to the id and type of related objects that encapsulate the hackish way this code obtains them.

```
DS.JSONSerializer.reopen

  # returns object related by given relationship.
  # 
  # The form can be related object, as-yet not unserialized
  # reference, or null
  getRelated: ( record, key ) ->
    related = Ember.get record, key
    if related?.then?
      if !related.isFulfilled
        related = record.get( 'data' )[ key ]
      else
        related = related.content
    return related

  getRelatedId: ( related ) ->
    return related.id || related

  serializeBelongsTo: (record, json, relationship) ->

    key = relationship.key
    belongsTo = @getRelated record, key
    key = @keyForRelationship?( key ) || key

    if Ember.isNone(belongsTo)
      json[key] = belongsTo
    else
      json[key] = @getRelatedId belongsTo

    if relationship.options.polymorphic
      this.serializePolymorphicType(record, json, relationship)

  serializeHasMany: (record, json, relationship) ->
    key = relationship.key
    relationshipType = DS.RelationshipChange.determineRelationshipType(
      record.constructor, relationship)

    # for opposite of one-to-many, default is to only save opposite
    if relationshipType is "manyToNone" or relationshipType is "manyToMany"
      related = @getRelated(record, key)
      if Ember.isNone(related)
        json[key]= related
      else
        json[key] = related.mapBy("id")
        if relationship.options.polymorphic
          this.serializePolymorphicType(record, json, relationship)
    return

  serializePolymorphicType: (record, json, relationship) ->
    key = relationship.key
    kind = relationship.kind
    convert = (related)=>
      if !Ember.isNone(related)
        typeKey = related.constructor.typeKey || related.type
        return {
          id: @getRelatedId related
          type: typeKey
        }
      else
        related
    related = @getRelated( record, key )
    key = @keyForAttribute?(key) || key
    if kind == 'belongsTo'      
      json[key] = convert( related )
    else if (kind == 'hasMany' )
      json[key] = related.content.map (rel)->
        convert(rel)
    else
      Ember.assert(
        'Relationship kind {#relationship.kind} not supported yet', false )
```